# Appweb is not found

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have created an sharepoint app which just contains a blank page. When I use vs2012 and hit f5 to debug the app is installed and works perfectly.  when, I use publish and get the. App file and upload it to the app catalog of the web application,the app displays in the catalog. As a user when I add/install it and click trust, the appweb seems to be not created. There are no errors in installing. But whrn I click the app after installation, I just get a page could not be displayed.

Am I missing a step which vs does for me? I read that the app web will be created automatically as long as you have sharepoint artifact. Ive exhausted my options already and I am just lost on how to do this. I even tried to go to appnewreg.aspx but it still does not have an appweb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference when using visual studio. When using visual studio and you hit f5, part of the deploy will install the application. Visual Studio then gets the appweb that was created then add it to the local hosts file. So when you click the app web it can locate it. If you did not setup your dns correctly, you will get an error that the server could not be found. which does not mean that the app web was not created.

In the end, it was a DNS problem which caused this because there was a lacking CName record for *..

Answer (score 0):

In the AppManifest.xml make sure that you provide the StartPage with a full url address:

```
<Properties>
    <Title>My App</Title>
    <StartPage>https://myapp.appdomain.net/pages/default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
</Properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do manual entry of your app in host file and if it is not run in that way, then definitely its DNS issue.

even i have the similar problem here:

[SharePoint 2013 App web URL is not hosted in Host file through App Catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634854/sharepoint-2013-app-web-url-is-not-hosted-in-host-file-through-app-catalog)

hope this may help..!!