# SharePoint 2013 App web URL is not hosted in Host file through App Catalog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localhost, sharepoint-2013, host, sharepoint-apps

I have deployed SharePoint 2013 App on some site collection using VS2012 then App is successfully deployed on that site, but when i am going to deploy the same app using App catalog , then it giver me "Server not found" Error.

I have verify this that when i have deployed the App using VS2012, App URL has registered to Host file and its accessible, But when i am using App catalog, App URL is not registered to Host file this time, And its not accessible, Manual entry of that URL in Host file will successfully  redirect me to the App.

Thanks in Advance.

Rishi

Comment: Hi did you get any luck regarding the same , as i am facing same problem

Comment: I got this error long time ago, To fix this you need to setup App environment correctly.